# Can I have a simple list of a dataclass field

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

Can I have easily a list of field from a `dataclass` ?

```
@dataclass
class C:
    x: int
    y: int
    z: int
    t: int
```

expected result:

```
[x,y,z,t]
```

Comment: Why wouldn't the output include `t`?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The answer depends on whether or not you have access to an object of the class.

#### Just using the class

If you only have access to the class, then you can use [`dataclasses.fields(C)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.fields) which returns a list of field objects (each of which has a `.name` property):

```py
[field.name for field in dataclasses.fields(C)]
```

#### From an existing object

If you have a constructed object of the class, then you have two additional options:

1. Use `dataclasses.fields` on the object:

```py
[field.name for field in dataclasses.fields(obj)]
```

2. Use [`dataclasses.asdict(obj)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.asdict) (as pointed out by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58693300/3780389)) which returns a dictionary from field name to field value. It sounds like you are only interested in the `.keys()` of the dictionary:

```py
dataclasses.asdict(obj).keys()       # gives a dict_keys object
list(dataclasses.asdict(obj).keys()) # gives a list
list(dataclasses.asdict(obj))        # same
```

#### Full example

Here are all of the options using your example:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, fields, asdict


@dataclass
class C:
    x: int
    y: int
    z: int
    t: int

# from the class
print([field.name for field in fields(C)])

# using an object
obj = C(1, 2, 3, 4)

print([field.name for field in fields(obj)])
print(asdict(obj).keys())
print(list(asdict(obj).keys()))
print(list(asdict(obj)))
```

Output:

```
['x', 'y', 'z', 't']
['x', 'y', 'z', 't']
dict_keys(['x', 'y', 'z', 't'])
['x', 'y', 'z', 't']
['x', 'y', 'z', 't']
```

Comment: I think I'll include that solution as part of my dataclass method for convenience: `def fields(self) -> list:` `return [field.name for field in fields(self)]`.

Answer (score 14):

You can use the [asdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.asdict) method of the `dataclasses` module. For example:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict


@dataclass
class Person:
    age: int
    name: str


adam = Person(25, 'Adam')

# if you want the keys

print(asdict(adam).keys()) # dict_keys(['age', 'name'])

# if you want the values

print(asdict(adam).values()) # dict_values([25, 'Adam'])
```

Both methods above return a `View` object which you can iterate on, or you can convert it to `list` using `list(...)`.

Comment: asdict(instance).keys().... can it be done on Nc class object ?

Comment: on your dataclass object e.g: `obj = C(1,2,4,5)`  you can call `obj.asdict().keys()`. I hope it is clear @SylvainPage.

Comment: I don't know why but obj.asdict() returns me "C has no attribute asdict". This why I do asdict(obj).keys().... My import was from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict. Never mind it works as well as C.__dataclass_fields__.keys() ...

Comment: @SylvainPage you can review the docs, the link exist in the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not usable for frozen dataclasses, resulting in `FrozenInstanceError` exception.

Comment: @SylvainPage You need `from dataclasses import asdict` and then you can call `asdict(C())` to get the dict.

Comment: Thanks for the additional comment Patrick, that worked for me!

Comment: Is this answer not wrong? I believe the correct use is `asdict(obj)`, not `obj.asdict()`.

Comment: This answer is certainly wrong, there is no such thing as an "asdict" method on the dataclass instance, there is function asdict that can be imported and used on the instances. I'm surprised this has so many upvotes and was marked as accepted response until recently when it doesn't work and can't work.

Comment: @Disruption, thank you for your note, I have update the answer

Comment: Please keep in mind that if your dataclass stores more complicated objects (e.g. other dataclasses), `asdict` will convert them to dictionaries as well. So technically, they're not the original values of that dataclass. For example, you'd lose the ability to call their methods.
That is the reason why I prefer to use `[getattr(adam, field.name) for field in fields(adam)]` than `asdict(adam).values()`.